# Cannot find module in typescript, but it seems that "tsc --traceResolution" resolves it successfully

Tags: node.js, typescript

I'm using MacOS BigSur, nodejs v16.13.2, typescript v4.6.3.

This is my github-repo: https://github.com/DanmoSAMA/performant-template/tree/feat/monorepo, please check detailed configuration here.

tsconfig.json:

```json
{
  "extends": "../../tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "lib": ["esnext"],
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "baseUrl": "./src"
  },
  "include": ["src"]
}
```

In router.ts, I import another module: `import TestController from 'controllers/test.controller'`

However, run `pnpm dev` will throw Error:

```
Error: Cannot find module 'controllers/test.controller'
Require stack:
- /Users/cuiyuming/Public/coding/performant-template/packages/backend/src/router.ts
```

I tried to check logs with `tsc --traceResolution`:

```
'baseUrl' option is set to '/Users/cuiyuming/Public/coding/performant-template/packages/backend/src', using this value to resolve non-relative module name 'controllers/test.controller'.
Resolving module name 'controllers/test.controller' relative to base url '/Users/cuiyuming/Public/coding/performant-template/packages/backend/src' - '/Users/cuiyuming/Public/coding/performant-template/packages/backend/src/controllers/test.controller'.
Loading module as file / folder, candidate module location '/Users/cuiyuming/Public/coding/performant-template/packages/backend/src/controllers/test.controller', target file type 'TypeScript'.
File '/Users/cuiyuming/Public/coding/performant-template/packages/backend/src/controllers/test.controller.ts' exist - use it as a name resolution result.
======== Module name 'controllers/test.controller' was successfully resolved to '/Users/cuiyuming/Public/coding/performant-template/packages/backend/src/controllers/test.controller.ts'. ========
```

It seems that the module was resolved successfully, so I don't know what to do. Can anyone tell me how to fix it, plz?

Comment: Hi, did you manage to fix this? I am facing the same issue, `--traceResolution` outputs `======== Module name 'config' was successfully resolved to` but when I run my app I get a `Error: Cannot find module 'config'`. I am using Fastify and a pretty straight forward TS configuration

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix this thanks to [this](https://github.com/TypeStrong/ts-node/issues/422).
You can either modify your start script along the lines of `NODE_PATH=./src ts-node ./src/app/index.ts`, or add `NODE_PATH=./src` to your .env file.

Just make sure that the value of `NODE_PATH` is equal to your typescript `baseUrl`.